# WSO DSS 3.5.0 Quality of Service Configuration Panel empty

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server

Kinda new to *WSO* products. Installed *WSO DSS 3.5.0* and created a simple test data service following all the instructions on WSO documentation. it is working fine except I can not find out how to implement the security for data service as mentioned in the documentation :

> https://docs.wso2.com/display/DSS350/Filtering+Content+to+Specific+User+Roles

The problem is that **Q**uality **O**f **S**ervice Configuration Panel is empty in my web console and no menu exists there for security or anything else except the edit data service menu as you can see :

[image]

Spending a full day reading docs searching googling etc for the solution I have not found any..

Anyone else facing this same issue? should I activate it in features somehow or is there another product needed to be installed together with DSS for this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WSO2 DSS 3.5.0 is carbon kernel 4.4.x based product. From kernel 4.4.x on wards QoS features are removed from the kernel.
You have to use WSO2 Developer Studio to implemnet QoS for the requirement.